TabView Publisher Leak Explanation
Upon looking for memory leak during a code review, I noticed one that I could not totally understand.
I isolated the code to reproduce it, the debug memory graph tells me that the issue comes from the @Published var currentPage.
But somehow, I can't understand exactly what's happening, can someone help me to see what's the problem?
// Edit: 1. This code snippet is a dumbed down version intended to show the issue I encountered. 2. This post aims at understanding the Why it's leaking rather than finding any specific solution to the issue
Here is some context about how I create the leak:

I set this ProblematicView inside a UIHostingController as a root view
Then I use a UINavigationController to push it
Finally I use the back btn of the Nav to pop it, there is nothing retaining the view from that point. I tested it with other view that indeed are correclty removed from memory.

So here it is:
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
class TheProblematicViewModel: ObservableObject {

    // The Suspect nº1
    @Published var currentPage = 0

    var slides: [TutorialSlide] = [ .init() ]
}

struct TutorialSlide {}


struct TheProblematicView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = TheProblematicViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        PagerView(
            tabItems: viewModel.slides,
            currentPage: $viewModel.currentPage
        )
    }
}

struct PagerView: View {

    var tabItems: [TutorialSlide]

    @Binding var currentPage: Int

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $currentPage) {
            ForEach(tabItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in

                PageView(slide: tabItems[index])
                    .tag(index)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PageView: View {

    var slide: TutorialSlide

    var body: some View { EmptyView() }
}



Here is a look at the memory graph. I see the thick lines indicating Strong-Ref? Right? But then I lose track of things after the ObservableObjectPublisher

I expected to see again a reference to the ViewModel somewhere inside the Publisher path, but it ends in obscure metadatas and stuff like that.
Can I learn more from the memory graph, if yes, how would I do that? (I'm not the most experienced user of the memory graph)

In SwiftUI the View structs are the view model already you shouldn't have classes or will run into issues. Need to learn @State and @Binding. @StateObject is only for when you need a reference type for some reason, not common nowadays since we have .task.

"View ... shouldn't have classes or will run into issues"? Then why bother creating @StateObject or @EnvironmentObject in the first place then? Not sure where you're going with that argument?
Even Apple suggest the use of deported logic in objects in their basic tutorials, rather than having the View containing everything.
What's the point of commenting on the use of X/Y when the code is explicitly declared as a snippet btw?

In that tutorial they need an object lifetime for their fetcher, you don't. And that tutorial could be updated to replace StateObject with the new .task for the same lifetime. In your code try using @State for currentPage.

Here comes the last part of my comment tho, this is a snippet that I've dumbed down and formatted to isolate the part of the code I don't get. It's like I ask why is my car doing that noise and you just come telling me I shouldn't have picked the yellow paint option lmao
